# Angular Smart Table not updating using $broadcast from different controller

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I'm using Angular Smart Table, which works fine when in same controller.  My problem is I want to update a list using `$broadcast/$on` from different controller.

Using log displays, I can see the `$on` clause executing and adding object to list, but I cannot see the new row in smart table unless I refresh page (access db).  I'm using `ng-route` for routing.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: are you using the stSafeSrc attribute?

Comment: Some code is always helpful...

Comment: are you using `$scope` or `$rootScope` on your `$broadcast` ??